# Digit Extraction for HE Bootstrapping

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

I was wondering if someone could explain the **Digit Extraction** from [HElib](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/873.pdf) in simple words:

> Apply a homomorphic (non-linear) digit-extraction procedure, computing $r$ ciphertexts that contain the digits $e − e′ + r − 1$ through $e − e′$ of the integers in the slots, respectively,
> relative to plaintext space mod-$p^r$. This requires that we generalize the bit-extraction procedure from
> [21] to a digit-extraction procedure for any prime power $p^r \ge 2$, this is done in Section 5.3. Once we
> extracted all these digits, we can combine them to get an encryption of the coefficients of $m$ in the
> slots relative to plaintext space modulo $p^r$.

Comment: I've added the relevant section to the question. Please point out what you don't understand from it, as others may find that a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Op simply doesn't want to read the referred article that the quote only mention it.

Comment: I don't make those kind of assumptions, but as it is the question will probably be closed as "too broad".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, Thank you for the precise answer and for allowing me to narrow down my question. I will come back with more intelligent question if this question survives :-)

Comment: @kelalaka, I have gone through so many articles/codes/other-materials to understand the tricks behind bootstrapping. Probably I might not have proper mathematical background to understand it. I will keep trying regardless of my inefficacy and online bullying. There always exists some altruist people (like @MaarteenBodewes) to help others.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/what-exactly-is-bootstrapping-in-fhe?rq=1

Comment: kelalaka is not such a bully as you can see from them pointing out the extra information :) There is no need to post another question, you can just [edit] this one and indicate where you're stuck.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, Thanks sir. I will take a closer look and come up with some more prudent questions. Thanks for the privileges :-)
This time, I will edit the question.

Comment: The lemma 1 in [GHS11](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/680.pdf) states that: Let $q = 2^r + 1$ for a positive integer $r$, and let $z$ be a non-negative integer smaller than $\frac{q^2}{2} - q$, such that $[z]_q$ is also negative, $[z]_q \in [0, \frac{q}{2}]$. Then $[[z]_q]_2 = z \langle r \rangle \oplus z \langle 0 \rangle$.


Does it mean, consider those $z$ for which $[z]_q$ is non-negative?

Or, does it mean, if $0 \leq z < (\frac{q^2}{2} - q)$ then $[z]_q \in [0, \frac{q}{2}]$?

Keep in mind that, $[\cdot]_q$ maps an integer in-between $(\frac{-q}{2}, \frac{q}{2}]$.