# Is it possible to use Batching with any of the Partial Homomorphic Cryptosystems?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption, paillier

I'm familiar with the concept of [batching](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86140/what-is-batching-in-homomorphic-encryption) in the context of (Fully) Homomorphic Encryption - whereby many values can be encrypted as a single ciphertext and operated on simultaneously in an SIMD/vector-processing like manner.

Is it possible to utilise batching with any of the Partial Homomorphic Encryption schemes (such as Pailler, ElGamal, etc.)? I have only seen batching discussed in the context of Levelled and Fully Homomorphic Cryptosystems previously (from Generation 2 onwards, *e.g. BFV, TFHE, CKKS*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The batching technique depends on the underlying algebra used for BFV/BGV/CKKS schemes where you can represent one large ciphertext/plaintext as many small ciphertexts/plaintexts in those schemes. But this property does not exist for Paillier or ElGamal.

Note that TFHE usually does not use batching.